# URI of Apex REST Class

Tags: apex, webservices, rest

I have created the following class

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Expense/*')
global class ExpenseWS
{


@HttpPost
global static void createExpense(String ExpenseName,String Type,Integer Amount)
{

Expenses__c e = new Expenses__c();

e.Expense_Name__c = ExpenseName;
e.Type__c = Type;
e.Amount__c = Amount;

insert e;



}


}
```

And I am able to successfully insert a expense using workbench REST explorer as shown below.

[image]

I would like to get the URI (endpoint) for this particular REST class so that I can invoke this REST resource from another org.

As per the guides I need to use the following notation.

https://ap2.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Expense

I am not sure whether this is right because there is no unique org identifier in the above URI.
There could be thousands of instances under *ap2.salesforce.com*

I hope I am making sense.

Q : How to get the endpoint/URI for the above REST resource ?

**UPDATE
Thanks .
The scenario which I am testing consist of two SF orgs..one sending expense data and another inserting expense data.**

**As such I have added the second org which absorbs the data sent (i.e where the post rest resource exists) in the first org's "Security Controls"->"Remote Site Settings".**

I observed the following .

[image]

[image]

**Can someone explain why the /services/apexrest/expense part of the URL is not accepted as endpoint by Salesforce ?**

Comment: You have to authenticate before you can call the rest resource. You authentication is what allows you to access the endpoint

Comment: Thanks Eric...so let me understand this...let us say I want this webservice to be public to the whole world..then the only way to achieve that is via Sites..am I right ?

Comment: Someone chime in here if I am wrong but I believe so. https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to authenticate before you can call the rest resource. You authentication is what allows you to access the endpoint

> A little while ago, Paul McGurn blogged how to create a public
>   (SOAP-based) web service via a Force.com Site. As Paul explains, you
>   add your web service class to the Enabled Apex Classes in the Site’s
>   Public Access Settings. You’ll also need to add the appropriate object
>   and field-level permissions for any data you will be exposing;
>   remembering, of course, that this web service will be accessible
>   without any authentication!
>
> As I was setting up a WebHook the other day, I realized that the same
>   principle applies to Apex REST Methods – add the class and any
>   relevant objects/fields to your Site’s Public Access Settings, and you
>   can access the REST methods via the Site URL. Let’s code up a simple
>   example; here’s my Apex class:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html

Comment: Great mate..tx for the help..just one more thing..I have updated the question..can you please provide your inputs..cheers !

Comment: Please close out this question and ask that as a new question. It helps keep things better organized for people looking for similar issues (seeing this one answered and searching for the second one)

Comment: Sure...I have created the following question for the second part http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/92972/remote-site-setting-salesforce-to-salesforce