# Remote Site Setting - Salesforce to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, apexrest, remote-site

I have two Salesforce orgs (Alpha & Beta).

Both of them are developer orgs and both of them exist in **ap2.salesforce.com**.

The scenario that I am trying to implement is as soon as expense is created in Alpha the same expense data will be created in Beta also.

There is a POST REST Class created in Beta which can accept Expense data and insert it in it's org.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Expense/*')
global class ExpenseWS {
    @HttpPost
    global static void createExpense(String ExpenseName,String Type,Integer Amount) {    
        Expenses__c e = new Expenses__c();

        e.Expense_Name__c = ExpenseName;
        e.Type__c = Type;
        e.Amount__c = Amount;

        insert e;
    }
}
```

Alpha calls Beta via Webservice callout (from trigger) as shown below.

```
trigger ExpenseIntegrate on Expense__c (after insert) {
    IntegrateExpenses.sendExpense(Trigger.new[0].Expense_Name__c,Trigger.new[0].Type__c,Integer.valueOf(Trigger.new[0].Amount__c));
}
```

I am not able to proceed further because I am not sure how to set the endpoint aka the URI of the REST class from Beta.

I thought I can set something like shown below but I am pretty sure that this is wrong as https://ap2.salesforce.com does not uniquely identify the second org (Beta)

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use OAuth to establish the connection first then only you can call the rest method from a different org. Please find this SFSE link for details. [How can i integrate one SFDC org to another SFDC using Rest Api](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/25021/how-can-i-integrate-one-sfdc-org-to-another-sfdc-using-rest-api)